# Separating row values with different lengths and removing one of the values

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm trying to manipulate a dataset into tidy format to use for a project, but I've gotten stuck on separating my row values into different columns, as some of them have extra values, but they are to the left of the information I need.

My data set starts off with the first column in each row with Location/ID/Year

```
# A tibble: 6 x 190
  Strains_w_Seq `HK/1/1968` `HK/107/1971` `BI/21793/1972` `EN/42/1972` 
  <chr>         <chr>       <chr>         <chr>           <chr>                
1 BI/16190/1968 640         0             640             320                     
2 BI/16398/1968 1163        0             0               1163                   
3 HK/1/1968     1280        1280          0               2560                  
4 BI/808/1969   320         0             0               640                    
5 BI/908/1969   1280        0             0               640                    
6 BI/17938/1969 554         0             0               453
```

But it ends with the following format: Type/Location/ID/Year

```
A tibble: 6 x 190
  Strains_w_Seq `HK/1/1968` `HK/107/1971` `BI/21793/1972` `EN/42/1972` 
  <chr>         <chr>       <chr>         <chr>           <chr>            
1 A/ONTARIO/RV… 0           0             0               0                       
2 A/ONTARIO/RV… 0           0             0               0                       
3 A/ONTARIO/RV… 0           0             0               0
```

I want to remove the "A" before the rest of values which are the information I need to keep. My thinking would be to make a "placeholder" column of NAs before values without the "A" and then separate the entire thing into a vector of 4 objects.

Ex:

```
NA/BI/16398/1968
NA/BI/16398/1968
NA/BI/16398/1968
NA/BI/16398/1968
...
A/TAIWAN/864/2007 
A/TAIWAN/864/2007
A/TAIWAN/864/2007
A/TAIWAN/864/2007
```

This would make it so I can separate based upon the "/" and then simply remove the column of NA I added & extra A's.

I've tried using the separate function and then dropping the extra, but that causes it to drop the last value (Year) and put A's in the "Geo_Origin" column

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- separate(df, Strains_w_Seq, into = c("Geo_Origin", "Strain_Num", "Isolation_Year"), sep = "/", extra = "drop")
```

I don't think I can use fill = "left" since there's no actual information to the left to pull.

To keep my data from getting lost I ended with:

```
df <- separate(df, Strains_w_Seq, into = c("Geo_Origin", "Strain_Num", "Isolation_Year"), sep = "/", extra = "merge")
```

The top ~800 observations get handled correctly, with

```
TAIWAN  864  2007
TAIWAN  864  2007
```

But I still get ~200 observations at the bottom with:

```
A  TAIWAN  864/2007
A  TAIWAN  864/2007
A  TAIWAN  864/2007
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data frame is called `df`, this can be done using `sub`

```
df$Strains_w_Seq = sub("^A/", "", df$Strains_w_Seq)
```

Comment: This would add an A to the entire column though correct?

I tried subsetting the rows that need the A added with this
```df[1:512,1] <- sub("^A/", "", df[,1])```
where [,1] is the Strains_w_Seq column, but it changed those rows to this:
```c("BI/15793/1968", "BI/16190/1968", "BI/16398/1968", "HK/1/1968", "BI/808/1969", "BI/908/1969", "BI/17938/1969", "BI/93/1970", "BI/2668/1970", "BI/6449/1971", "BI/21438/1971", "BI/21801/1971", "HK/107/1971", ...)```
with each row now having the entire list of the 512 row IDs.

Comment: This is because you are subsetting them wrong.  You are picking up an entire column `[,1]` and assigning it to only first 512 rows `[1:512,1]`.  That being said, you do not need to add `A` to any values before removing them again.  Just run this command as I mentioned in the answer after you read your data.  As long as your data looks like the way it looks at the top of your question, it should work.  It will replace the A in front of the values if it exists.  If there is no A, then nothing is changed.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this was removing the "^A". It worked, thanks!